# Primeiro Plano/Segundo Plano Aplicativo Android

Tags: android

Bom dia galera! sou novato em android, preciso verificar se o aplicativo está em primeiro ou segundo plano, se estiver em segundo ele precisa voltar para primeiro plano e caso o usuário finalize o aplicativo ele reabra.

conto com a ajuda de vocês

Comment: Você não acha coloca esse tipo de comportamento num app parece ser meio imperativo? Parece que você quer que o app fique aberto de qualquer jeito, queira o user ou não, isso pode fazer o usuário desgostar do seu app. Sem contar que, pelas configs, não tem como evitar que um app seja fechado.

Comment: eu sei! mas  usuário pediu isso! rsrs, não é algo que pensei em fazer por conta própria nao

Comment: Ah sim, mas já te adiantei, se um usuário for nas opçoes do aplicativo, e "forçar parada", não há nada que você possa fazer.

Comment: @DiegoDiasMól e Outra, o controle de aplicativos quem faz é o próprio sistema operacional, se quiser deixar algo rodar o tempo todo, crie um service pra isso.

Comment: é isso! pensei em criar alguma forma de bloquear(com senha ou sem senha mesmo) a abertura de outro aplicativo que não seja o que o usuário quer

Comment: Existe controle de usuarios no android. Isso que você parece querer fazer é um sistema de acessos e permissões. Talvez não seja viavel fazer isso, uma vez que esse controle todo talvez exija acesso root.

Comment: fazendo root, eu poderia deixar só o meu app, sendo acionado ao ligar o aparelho